# Every vector in a Hilbert space has a Fourier representation wrt an orthonormal sequences?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series

I'm reading Kreyszig's text, and there is a Theorem in section 3.5 stating:

**Theorem**: Let $(e_k)$ be an orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space $H$. Then

1) If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k e_k$ converges then the coefficients $\alpha_k$ are the Fourier coefficients  $\langle x, e_k \rangle$, where $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k e_k$, so that $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k$.

2) For all $x \in H$ the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k$ converges (in the norm of $H$).

I would like to check my understanding here. I believe we can then say that, given some orthonormal sequence $(e_k)$ and a fixed $x \in H$, we have that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k$ converges by part 2). Then, by part 1), we can write $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k$. So every $x \in H$ can be represented as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k$? Is my logic correct here?

Comment: The conclusion is incorrect, as an orthogonal sequence is not necessarily an orthogonal basis. Consider for example $\mathscr l^2$ with standard orthogonal basis $\{e_k\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$. Then consider the orthogonal sequence $\{b_k\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$ with $b_k=e_{k+1}$. You will have for example with $x=e_1$ that $\langle x, b_k\rangle=0$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$, but $x\neq 0 = \sum \langle x, b_k \rangle b_k$.

Comment: Thanks, I like this counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conclusion is too strong. By (2) you can conclude that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$ converges to some $y$, but you cannot conclude that $y=x$. Then by (1) you know that $y=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\langle y,e_k\rangle e_k$. So you can conclude that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\langle y,e_k\rangle e_k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$, which implies that $y-x$ is orthogonal to every $e_k$ for $1 \le k < \infty$.